# Choose the table view when I should search words

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have 2 tables in one view controller and a search bar . The functionality of first view controller and the search bar was ok , untill i added the second table. Now when i want to search something , the research is in the table number one , and i don't want this .

Here is my code :

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.searchResult removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

    self.searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag==1) {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResult count];
    }
    else
    {return [self.tableData count];}

    }
    else return historique.count;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[content objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"headerTitle"];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [content valueForKey:@"headerTitle"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [indices indexOfObject:title];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (tableView.tag==1) {
        return  [content count];
    }else
    return 1;
}


UITableViewCell *cell ;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if (tableView.tag==0) {

 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
        else

        cell.textLabel.text = [historique objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }


    if (tableView.tag==1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
    }}
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    DefinitionViewController *secondViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"definition"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSString *uu;

    if ([[transaction valueForKey:str] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        NSLog(@"yes");
        NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)[transaction valueForKey:str];
        uu = [jsonArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        secondViewController.definitionsArray=jsonArray;


    }

    else{
        uu=[transaction valueForKey:str];

    }

    NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"histroriqueValues"]];
    [values addObject:uu];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:values forKey:@"histroriqueValues"];
    historiqueValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"histroriqueValues"]mutableCopy];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

tableView.tag=0 is the table where i want to make the search. I put breakpoints , and when i click on search bar the table where the search is making is tableView.tag=1.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small example projects with a UITableViewController. If you need, i can push it to a github repo so you can grab it and build on it.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  filterExample
//
//  Created by François Chabbey on 16.04.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 François Chabbey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *content;
    NSArray *filteredContent;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    content = @[@"CECI",@"CELA",@"CELUI-CI",@"ET CA",@"ETC"];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchString];
    filteredContent = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[content filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    return YES;
}




-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView  == self.tableView) {
        return content.count;
    } else {
        return filteredContent.count;
    }
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"test"];
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text =  content[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = filteredContent[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: and even if i put like this     self.tableSource= self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
 the result is the same.

Comment: Have you instantiated the two tableview in your code. I look at the documentation and some example from Apple, and it seems that the searchDisplayController come with its own created tableview, so you dont have to create another tableview. You could discriminate between the two table, look at my edit